# "Number of referencing columns in foreign key differs from number of referenced columns" inline error

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, ddl

I'm trying to create a Section table that refers to Time Slot table.details of attributes is shown in the picture. how to declare foreign key constraint? Red line is where I get this error

```
create table Section 
(   
    course_id nvarchar(8) foreign key references Course(course_id) on delete cascade,
    sec_id nvarchar(8),
    semester nvarchar(6) check(semester in ('Spring','Fall','Summer','Winter')),
    year_ numeric(4,0) check(1700 < year_ and year_ < 2100),
    building nvarchar(15),
    room_number nvarchar(7), 
    time_slot_id nvarchar(4),
    primary key(course_id,sec_id,semester,year_),
    --Foreign key =>(Section to Classroom)
    constraint FK_Section_to_Classroom 
    foreign key(building,room_number) 
    references Classroom(building,room_number)
    on delete set null,
    --Foreign key =>(Section to TimeSlot)
    constraint FK_Section_to_TimeSlot 
    foreign key(time_slot_id) 
    references TimeSlot(time_slot_id,day_of_week,start_time)
    on delete set null
);
```

```
create table TimeSlot
(
    time_slot_id nvarchar(4),
    day_of_week nvarchar(1) check(day_of_week in ('M', 'T', 'W', 'R', 'F', 'S', 'U')),
    start_time time,
    end_time time,
    primary key(time_slot_id,day_of_week,start_time)
);
```

[Section table and Time Slot table DDL in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpW3v.jpg)

The Section table foreign key is one single attribute that I want to refer to primary key of Time slot table in which is a set of attributes. Is there any other way to declare foreign key constraint?

Comment: 1 <> 3. (time_slot_id) can't reference (time_slot_id,day_of_week,start_time).

Comment: One `time_slot_id` can have many different rows in the `TimeSlot` table. Should each row in `Section` refer to multiple rows in `TimeSlot`, or just one row?

Comment: @MatBailie yes one time_slot_id have many different rows in the Time Slot table. for example 'A', 'M', 8:00, 8:50 another one is 'A', 'W', 8:00, 8:50 or 'A', 'F', 8:00, 8:50 and so on. and each row in Section can refer to multiple row in Time Slot for example we have these tuples in Section : 'CS-100', '1', 'Fall', '2017', 'Packard', '101', 'H' 
                                and 'CS-100', '1', 'spring', '2018', 'Packard', '101', 'F'

Comment: Add that to your question as formatted text, not an unformatted comment. *(Please read [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952))*

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to declare a foreign key from `Section` to `TimeSlot`.

That would be explicity stating that each row in `Section` refers to ***one*** row in `TimeSlot`. Your comment confirms that is ***not*** what you want.

What you're describing requires a third table to act as a link / association.

```
CREATE TABLE DimTimeSlot (
  id             INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  time_slot_id   NVARCHAR(4)  PRIMARY KEY
);

create table Section 
(   
    ...
    time_slot_id nvarchar(4),
    ...
    --Foreign key =>(Section to DimTimeSlot)
    constraint FK_Section_to_DimTimeSlot 
      foreign key(time_slot_id) 
      references DimTimeSlot(time_slot_id)
        on delete set null
);

create table TimeSlot
(
    time_slot_id nvarchar(4),
    ...
    --Foreign key =>(TimeSlot to DimTimeSlot)
    constraint FK_TimeSlot_to_DimTimeSlot 
      foreign key(time_slot_id) 
      references DimTimeSlot(time_slot_id)
        on delete cascade
);
```

This way...

If a row in DimTimeSlot is deleted the rows in Section get set to NULL and the rows in TimeSlot get deleted.

A row in Section references one row in DimTimeSlot, but that references N rows in TimeSlot.